# Issue loading external files (CSS and JavaScript) in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I'm having a bizarre situation here where my external site files, both JavaScript and CSS, are being interpretted as somehow corrupt on Safari browsers. The same site looks fine in Internet Explorer, but on Safari the javascript and css are being completely ignored. If I look at the files through the Inspector, I can see that Safari views these files as containing junk characters -- either asian symbols or square boxes. When I navigate directly to the files, however, they appear just fine. See the site below, viewed in Safari 5, for an example:

http://amsoell.com/dch/castlemoore

If I embed the same exact CSS or JavaScript into the HTML itself, it renders perfectly. I don't know if this is a server issue or something in my CSS, but I'm at my wits end here.

Comment: It actually seems to be happening in everything *but* Internet Explorer (at least for me)...Let's see what's going on here.

Comment: Hm, I thought Bogdan's answer would work, because it's definitely a result of the encoding, but it seems despite the meta tag your file is still rendered as UTF-16. Do you have direct access to the server, or is it a shared host?

Comment: This is my server, so I've got full access. I tried opening all the files, converting to utf-8, and zapping all non-ascii characters. It worked for a bit, and then magically stopped working again after a few browser relaunches. I'm wondering if something on the server isn't converting these files from utf-8 to something else.

But to answer the question, I have access to the server if you have server-side suggestions.

Comment: I've checked a few times now and it seems to be consistently fixed now. Is it still randomly breaking? What happens is that the byte sequence 0xFF 0xFE is added to the beginning, indicating UTF-16 (little-endian), so if it's not you adding them, you could monitor the file for changes. What version of Ubuntu are you running, and is the page served up by PHP or just static HTML?

Comment: Yeah, for a while it was going back and forth, working and not, which makes me think it's an Apache problem. These are static HTML files, so it shouldn't be a PHP issue. But you're right, the page hasn't looked weird for a while now, so maybe the issue has miraculously resolved itself? Disconcerting, but I'll take it for now.

Thanks for the assist, Tim...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked your website for [validation](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Famsoell.com%2Fdch%2Fcastlemoore%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=XHTML+1.0+Transitional&ss=1&outline=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.781) and it's not valid. But the most interesting thing is that your enconding is `utf-16le`. You should put your encoding to `utf-8`. Just put the following line in your `<head>` section:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

Comment: The HTML may not pass validation, but that's not the problem here. I tried adding your meta tag, and that didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Include the `charset="utf-8"` parameter in your `<script>` and `<link>` tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="script.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" href="style.css">
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! CSS and js was not working in safari on macOS or chrome and safari on iOS and this fixed it

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by saving the html page in "**Windows-1252 Encoding**".