# My stylesheet doesn't load correctly in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

Help! My website at www.craminc.org displays correctly in IE but not in Firefox.  It's not using the stylesheet in Firefox. Can anyone help?

It was working fine, and I made a few small changes and now, it doesn't work.

I found a few weird things in the #left h1, and removed them, and removed the dropbox shadow, but that didn't help.

I wrote this HTML a while ago, and I see I should have used quotes around the div ids, but that doesn't fix the problem.

Thanks!

Here is the link

```
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I also have this in the

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

Here is the sheet

```
/*********** Cram Stylesheet -  By LKT ********/

body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background: white url(images/oldpaper.gif);
text-align: justify;
text-indent: 0px;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
color: #000;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
color: black;
text-indent: 18px;
}


/************* HEADER STUFF ************/

#header {
width: 1050px;
height: 120px;
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 10px 0px;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
background:  url(images/header.jpg);
}

#header h1 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 70px 0px;
    text-align: left;
    color: yellow;
    font-size: 85px;
}

/************* menu ************/

#menu {
        width: 1042px;
    height:17px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 4px;
    background: #330066;
}

#menu ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu li {
    display: inline;
}

#menu a {
    padding: 2px 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFF;
}

#menu a:hover {
    color: white;
}


/************* CONTENT ************/

#content {
    width: 1050px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #9EBDFF ;
}

#left {
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    color: #000000;
    background: #9EBDFF;
}

#left h1
    {
    margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:0.0001pt;
    font-size:14pt;
    font-family:Cambria;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    line-height: normal;
    border-bottom-width: medium;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    color: #000000;
}

#left h6
    {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: black;

}

#left a {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    color: #000066;
}
#left a:hover {
    color:white;
    }

#right {
    float: right;
    width: 790px;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

#right h1 {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #0033CC;
}

#right h3 {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}

#right h4 {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: left;
    color: black;
}

#right p {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: justify;
    color: #000000;
}



#right a:hover {
    color:navy;
}

#clearit   {
    clear: both;
}

/************* FOOTER ************/

#footer {
    clear: both;
    width: 1048px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    background: #7E9DFF;
    font-size: 9px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px;
    color: #000066;
}

#footer  a {
    padding: 0px 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    color: #000066;
}

#footer  a:hover {
    color:white;
    }
```

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.craminc.org&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Perhaps you could post the style sheet here so that we can take a look at it.

Comment: I have a feeling this should be worded as "as intended" not "correctly" because if it actually works in IE it's probably not "correct"

Comment: Your style sheet looks funky. It seems like you're having this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134329/issue-loading-external-files-css-and-javascript-in-safari

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to use an XHTML doctype, you **must** ensure that your code is valid. Failure to do so will result in rendering glitches or worse.

Your page has a lot of XHTML errors, mostly because you're using upper-case element names; the XHTML spec requires you to use lower-case for your element names.

You could go through the code and convert all your elements from `<DIV>` to `<div>` etc, but to be honest, there's no need for that -- you're not sticking to the XHTML specs, so clearly XHTML isn't important to you, so my suggestion is to just change your doctype.

Switch to the HTML5 doctype, and your page will be valid. This should go a long way toward solving your problems:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks - this is some old code I wrote when I was new.  I should probably rewrite the whole thing, but I would like to fix it quickly now since it is live.

Answer (score 0):

When I just tried to open your stylesheet in Firefox, it looked like a jumble of Japanese characters.  [CSS rendered in Japanese?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490216/css-rendered-in-japanese)

Comment: http://www.craminc.org/styles.css seems fine to me...but yeah, in firebug it shows those characters

Comment: I don't know if the FTP changed something.